# JArray.Load, not loading array? wrong format?

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

Trying to get this Bitfinex api library working, but get this exception.

A normal response.Content is

```
[["tBTCUSD",5694.5,90.04753567,5694.6,90.83915407,-155.4,-0.0266,5694.6,68727.10536905,6007.8,5537]]
```

and an error response.Content is

```
“[\”error\”,20060,\”maintenance”\]”
```

The normal response produces an exception

```
ArgumentException...Can not convert Array to String
```

at

```
var array = JArray.Load(reader); 
if((string)array[0] == "error")   // exception
```

I'm new to json, so there may well be a basic formatting issue here with the reader content. It seems this string is not converted to an array, and hence the array[0] holds an array..?

[image]

**EDIT:**

On further thought, I speculate the API content format may have changed. In case, it seems this may work to check for "error" at first element of an error-response :

```
 if ( array[0].GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(string)) && (string)array[0] == "error")
```

Comment: It will be good to have same structure for normal content and error content. As of now normal content is an array of an array whereas error content is array of strings. What you are trying to do is assuming error response when the content is that of normal response.

Comment: `array[0]` isn't a string.  It's an inner array.  How do you expect to cast an array to a string?

Comment: I see.. I assumed code was up-to-date with API, but that may of course not be the case. See edit.   @Amy,  I didn't know the Json formats, but now I see certainly this is an array of arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the response is valid, the JSON contains an array of arrays of values.  When the response is invalid, it contains an array of values, the first of which is the string `"error"`.

Therefore, after parsing with LINQ to JSON, you need to check the [`JToken.Type`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Type.htm) type of the first element in the outer array before casting it to a string (or an array), e.g. like so:

```
var array = JArray.Load(reader); 

if (array.Count > 0 && array[0].Type == JTokenType.String && (string)array[0] == "error")
{
    // Process an error response
    Console.WriteLine("Error response detected.");
}
else if (array.Count > 0 && array[0].Type == JTokenType.Array)
{
    // Process a successful response.
    Console.WriteLine("Normal response detected, array value: ");
    var arrayValue = (JArray)array[0];              
    Console.WriteLine(arrayValue);          
}
else
{
    // Completely unexpected response.
    throw new JsonException("Unexpected response");
}
```

Similarly, you could check to see whether `array[0]` is of .Net type [`JArray`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm) or [`JValue`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JValue.htm).

The operator you are using in the expression `(string)array[0]` -- [`JTokenExplicit Conversion (JToken to String)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_op_Explicit_28.htm) -- does not re-serialize an arbitrary `JToken` to JSON.  Instead, it converts that `JToken` to a string *only if it represents a primitive value such as a string or an integer*.  If you want to re-serialize `array[0]` to JSON you would need to use the [`ToString()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToString.htm) method like so:

```
if (array.Count > 0 && array[0].ToString(Formatting.None) == "\"error\"")
{
    // Process an error response                
}
else // Continue as before
{
}
```

However this will have worse performance than simply checking the type.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Dqp7Ew).

Comment: Appreciate the test class! I don't test proper, so that's a nice start for a better habit.